# Is aoMap only working for THREE.BufferGeometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How should I make an aoMap work for a normal THREE.Geometry? Is there a demo?

```
 var uvs = geometry.attributes.uv.array; 

 geometry.addAttribute('uv2', new THREE.BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));
```

Above code is for BufferGeometry.

Answer (score 2):

An `aoMap` requires the 2nd set of UVs. You can create a 2nd set of UVs by duplicating the first set if you want.

This is how to do it for `Geometry`:

```
geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 1 ] = geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ];
```

And this is how to do it for `BufferGeometry`:

```
var uvs = geometry.attributes.uv.array;
geometry.addAttribute( 'uv2', new THREE.BufferAttribute( uvs, 2 ) );
```

... or more simply:

```
geometry.attributes.uv2 = geometry.attributes.uv;
```

three.js r.88

Comment: This should absolutely be the accepted answer. I wish I had found this a long time ago.